# Inserting a text box with similar formatting as that of placeholder in Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I need to insert a text box where it's text contents should match the placeholder style.

The work around is hard. I need to set for the size, color, style etc. Instead if I can insert a placeholder and then strat typing the text will be straightforward.

Is there a way by using apps script I can insert a new placeholder in the working slide?

Comment: There is no placeholder method. But you can check the [Add a new text box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides). All of the supported methods are found in the [Apps Scripts Slides Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides). If what you're trying to do is not specified there, it's not supported yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly-- placeholders are copied from layouts on slide creation. If you want a new placeholder, add it to the layout and then create your slide. If you just want another box in the slide that has the same text styles, I'd recommend calling [duplicate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#duplicate()) on the placeholder.

Comment: So there is no means of inserting a placeholder for an existing slide?